# Externalize the app-profiles in spring boot with multiple web apps running on tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, unix, tomcat9

I am new to spring boot and tomcat. I have multiple web application3 running in tomcat.

I have 3 web applications(spring boot) running on tomcat namely, app1, app2 and app3. In my app-profile, I have 3 yaml files(one for each app).

```
application-app1.yml
application-app2.yml
application-app3.yml
```

Also, my environment is set as below:

```
JAVA_OPTS='-Dspring.profile.active=uat,qa,default'
```

In /tomcat/webapp i have below folders:

```
app1
app2
app3
```

The app-profiles picks the external yml file when I add another file names as application-uat.yml
But, if this happens then all the application picks up same yml file.

My question:

How do I ensure that  particular yml files are picked up for that particular application?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the external config file names by configuring the `spring.config.additional-location` parameter in each applications `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.  Eg. for app1 you could have this configuration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>spring.config.additional-location</param-name>
    <param-value>file:./config/app1.yml</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```